# Regenerate BIOS boot partition

Tags: boot, grub2, bios, boot-partition

I deleted BIOS boot partition, and GRUB won't boot. 
I can boot via supergrubdisk , but it's not solve.
Can I regenerate it? 
(Without system reinstalling)

Comment: Have you tried boot repair from LiveUSB?

Comment: The bios_grub partition is unformatted space containing the core.img file for grub when using gpt partitioning and BIOS boot. You should just need to reinstall grub to gpt's protective MBR. If drive is sda: `sudo grub-install /dev/sda` from inside a otherwise working system. If that does not work, then a full reinstall of grub, usually easier with Boot-Repair or you can use chroot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try with live cd .

and follow this guide : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair[enter link description here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)